# Perl printing null timestamp to csv file

Tags: mysql, perl, timestamp

I am working on a perl script writing data to a *.csv file for mysql

The fields that i'm trying to set as `NULL` is a timestamp type
So, as mentionned on the internet, printing a null value for a timestamp data is `\N`
But Perl won't compile because of this. What should I add for Perl to compile, and Mysql to understand ?

```
print ECRIRE "non_recupere_$ip;$cs;$ip;$hostname;$image;$version;$modele;\N;$now;$mac;$communauteSNMP;$subnet;$netmask;$constructeur;;;;;\n";

Missing braces on \N{} at ../../../scripts/mynet/SW-parser3.pl line 175, near "$version;$modele"
Execution of ../../../scripts/mynet/SW-parser3.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

Putting the data as `;{\N};` is not working either.

Comment: "as mentionned on the internet, printing a null value for a timestamp data is \N". I think this is wrong. Where did you get it from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
print ECRIRE "non_recupere_$ip;$cs;$ip;$hostname;$image;$version;$modele;".'\N'.";$now;$mac;$communauteSNMP;$subnet;$netmask;$constructeur;;;;;\n";"
```

Seqences in single quotes are not evaluated.

`\N` is a special character in perl. See [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html)

> \N                Any character but newline.  Not in [].27.
>   \N{}     Named or numbered (Unicode) character or